# AWS KMS cloudformation template tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a cloudformation template for KMS key creation. Whilst the code works fine without tags but when I try to include tags, it pops up the error saying "Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 30, column 1)"
Not sure what exactly is going wrong here. Your help highly appreciated. Thanks. Here is the template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  akscmk:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      Description: "Encrypt sensitive data for Billboard site."
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: key-default-1
        Statement:
          - Sid: "Allow administration of the key"
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
            Action:
              - "kms:*"
            Resource: "*"
          - Sid: "Allow use of the key"
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: 'arn:aws:iam::0987654321:user/devuser'
            Action:
              - "kms:Encrypt"
              - "kms:Decrypt"
              - "kms:ReEncrypt"
              - "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
              - "kms:DescribeKey"
            Resource: "*"
      Tags:
        - Key: country
          Value: india
  KeyAlias:
    Type: 'AWS::KMS::Alias'
    Properties:
      AliasName: alias/testcmk
      TargetKeyId: !Ref akscmk
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html), the tag key and value are capped with a quote, type String.

```
Tags: 
  - 
    Key: "keyname1"
    Value: "value1"
  - 
    Key: "keyname2"
    Value: "value2"
```

Comment: Thanks Lamanus. Quotes aren't issue for sure. Same syntax worked for different template. I also tried capping key and values with a quote but that didn't work either.

Comment: Well, there is an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-key.html) and I don't get it what is wrong then.

Comment: I even tried `validate-template` with your template but there is no error message.

Comment: Thanks Lamanus, issue is resolved. All I did is remove the line which mentioned tags and add again not using copy paste but using spaces and writing again. Strange but it worked. Looks like formatting issue.